# Opening Browser in remote machine through ssh

Tags: browser, ssh

I need to open browser with specific url using ssh through a remote machine, i have enabled password less connection, i am able to get command o/p which run on remote machine using ssh, but how can i open browser using ssh?  Tried with "-X" option which will open remote machine browser in my machine ( considering i run ssh from my machine).

Tried
 1). `ssh client@IP_ADDRESS -X "firefox http://google.com`  - this opens browser in my machine.

2). `ssh client@IP_ADDRESS "firefox http://google.com` this command shows error saying `Error: no display specified`. 

 Basically, my requirement is , through my machine, i should launch browser with specific url in remote machine ( which is suse linux). 
 Any pointers are greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable. See `env |grep DISPLAY`.
So basically you could use something like `export DISPLAY=:0; firefox http://google.de`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what i tried, `ssh client@IP_ADDRESS "/usr/bin/firefox --display=X11 -new-tab=http://google.com` .But i got error<br/>`Error: cannot open display: X11`

Comment: So did my example work for you? If so, mark it as accepted please, so other users can easily find the valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the reply. I got this working with the help of 2 scripts

On Server side ( or in my machine) i have a script which looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh client@IP_ADDRESS "nohup sh openBrowser.sh $1" &
PID=$$;
echo "PID: $PID";
sleep 3 && kill -9 $PID;
```

On the client side ( where i need to open browser remotely i have a script ( openBrowser.sh) which looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
ps aux | grep [f]irefox && killall -9 firefox
nohup firefox --display=:0 $1 &
```

Also point to ensure that, I have created a password-less connection using ssh-keygen, on the server I call the script (first one) as

```
sh launchBrowser_client1.sh  http://google.com
```

This would open google.com on client. Your pointers on solving this appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a display to run it on. You specify that display using the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

If you don't want to shove all the data over SSH then you need to use an X11 server on the machine you are connecting to. This could be a headless server such as xvfb.

Comment: pls see my reply above. @keks - no, it gave me error saying unable to open display.

Comment: X11 is the protocol used to talk to the server, not the identifier for the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Below command seems to be partially working, i wrote a small script in remote machine its like, `#!/usr/bin/sh
no="ps aux | grep firefox | grep -vc grep";
if [[ "$no" > 0 ]];
then
 
 killall -9 firefox
fi
firefox --display=:0 $1 &
` , and i launch this command through my machine `ssh client@IP_ADDRESS "nohup sh openBrowser.sh google.com"`, this seems to be parially working, but its getting stuck in my machine, i need to pass Cntrl+C to come out. Is there any way to come out without passing Cntrl+C.