# Opening browser in client machine through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

Using linux, this link explains how to open a browser in the remote machine using ssh:

[Opening Browser in remote machine through ssh [ CLOSED ]](https://superuser.com/questions/583608/opening-browser-in-remote-machine-through-ssh-closed)

How can I instead see the remote machines browser on the client computer?
Sort of as with xclock...